# What is the idiomatic way to evaluate a modified argument in a Clojure macro?

Tags: clojure, macros, arguments, eval

Imagine my intent is to modify the syntax tree of an s-expression passed into the macro, by modifying the syntax tree, and then evaluating the modified argument. I could do something like the following:

```
(defmacro runargs [args]
  (eval (cons (first args) " buckeroo")))

(runargs (println "hi there"))
```

Now that doesn't *feel* idiomatic because I have whacked a big `eval` in the middle of my code.

Now I modify it slightly and come up with the following:

```
(defmacro runargs [args]
  `(~@(cons (first args) " buckeroo")))

(runargs (println "hi there"))
```

That has solved the `eval` issue. But I'm still left feeling like this isn't quite idiomatic.

My question is: **What is the idiomatic way to evaluate a modified argument in a Clojure macro?**

Comment: Could you supply your desired output, both AST-wise and the printed one? (Because the given code won't print `buckeroo` but `b u c k e r o o` and I'm not sure whether that's intended.)

Comment: My apologies. Let's assume that's intended.

Comment: The 'trick' with macros is to actually have a clear picture of what you want the code to look like once the macro is expanded. From this, you can identify the template for what you are trying to do. Once you have that, then the macro is fairly straight-forward to define. In most cases, you DON"T want the macro to evaluate the arguments - it is more about rearranging the arguments into a new form at compile time and then evaluated at run time. Consider what your macro would do if the argument was (inc x) instead of a println and a string - what is x at compile time? When should inc occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two examples you give do entirely different things. The first is evaluating the modified s-expression at *macroexpansion time*, which is almost certainly not what you want.

```
user=> (defmacro runargs-eval [args]
         (eval (cons (first args) " buckaroo")))
#'user/runargs-eval

user=> (macroexpand '(runargs-eval (println "hi there")))
  b u c k e r o o
nil

user=> (defmacro runargs [args]
         `(~@(cons (first args) " buckeroo")))
#'user/runargs

user=> (macroexpand '(runargs (println "hi there")))
(println \space \b \u \c \k \e \r \o \o)
```

There isn't much of a difference if you're simply evaluating a single s-expression that happens to contain a call to your macro, but if you're compiling code that uses your macro (as in the body of a lambda), macroexpansion happens at compile-time:

```
user=> (defn say-hello-eval [x] (runargs-eval (println x)))
  b u c k e r o o
#'user/say-hello-eval

user=> (say-hello-eval "hi there")
nil

user=> (defn say-hello [x] (runargs (println x)))
#'user/say-hello

user=> (say-hello "hi there")
  b u c k e r o o
nil
```

Macros are simply functions that accept an un-evaluated expression, and return a modified un-evaluated expression. It would be a very unusual situation if you actually wanted to evaluate the expression as part of the macroexpansion - normally your macro will just return the modified expression, and let the Clojure compiler take care of evaluating it at the appropriate time.

The syntax-quote in your second example isn't really necessary - the general use case for syntax quoting is when you're plugging macro arguments into a templated expression that contains symbols that should resolve to something in the namespace in which the macro is defined. If your macro is truly a syntactic transformation of an s-expression, then you can just operate on the expression as data like you would any other Clojure data structure:

```
(defmacro runargs [args]
  (cons (first args) " buckeroo"))
```